# munin-node worked fine, now "start operation timed out"

Tags: centos7, service, munin

I have had munin-node running successfully on my machine for a while, but since recently it won't start anymore. There is no munin-node log for me to check, and `systemctl status munin-node` does not give a lot of helpful information either:

```
[root@host /]# systemctl status munin-node
● munin-node.service - Munin Node
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/munin-node.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Tue 2021-05-18 23:35:16 CEST; 1h 8min ago
     Docs: man:munin-node(1)
           http://guide.munin-monitoring.org/en/latest/node/index.html
  Process: 7710 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/munin-node --foreground (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7710 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 18 23:33:44 host systemd[1]: Starting Munin Node...
May 18 23:35:14 host systemd[1]: munin-node.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
May 18 23:35:16 host systemd[1]: Failed to start Munin Node.
May 18 23:35:16 host systemd[1]: Unit munin-node.service entered failed state.
May 18 23:35:16 host systemd[1]: munin-node.service failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be plugins that were taking too long, specifically the `nvidia_gpu_*` plugins since it is a multi-gpu machine. There is no clear indicator that plugins were causing the timeout.

To speed up the `nvidia_gpu_*` plugins, I used the following command, based on https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-is-slow-on-ubuntu-16-04/50416:

```
nvidia_smi --persistence-mode 1
```

The effect of this can be tested by just running the `nvidia_smi` command, which will load much faster as the GPUs don't have to be woken up first.

Answer (score 0):

For Debian, timeout can be increased in `/etc/init.d/munin-node`:

> START_ARGS="--background --notify-await --notify-timeout 15"

e.g.

> START_ARGS="--background --notify-await --notify-timeout 120"

which fixed the problem for me on SysV Bullseye system.

as seen here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=954128